# How to swap 2 strings passed as pointers in a function?

Tags: c++, string

I have to swap 2 char strings that I passed as pointers into a function:
bool swap_strings (char* string1, char* string2)
if both strings have not same length return false, else if swapping worked, return true;

how can I realise this? why is this not correct :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


bool swap_strings(char * string1, char * string2) { 
    char * s;
    char * s2;
    char * tmp = nullptr;
        for (s = string1; *s != '\0'; ++s);
        for (s2 = string2; *s2 != '\0'; ++s2);
        if ((s - s2)  != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {      
            tmp = *&string1;
            string1 = *&string2;
            string2 = *&tmp;
            cout << tmp << string1 << string2<< endl;
        }

        return true;
    }



int main()
{

    bool da = false;
    char s1[] = "hallo1";
    char s2[] = "ababab";

    da = swap_strings(s1, s2); 

    cout << da << s1 << s2 <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char*`s for `s` and `s2` if you are using them to figure out a length?  Length is better implemented as an integer value.  Also, using `for` loops to figure out the length is unnecessary. Use `strlen()`

Comment: @BrianGradin `std::swap` uses a temporary internally.

Comment: That dense accumulation of invalid code makes me shiver!

Comment: what is that? string1 ^= string2 ^= string1 ^ string2;

Comment: I may not use inbuilt functions like swap..

Comment: Sorry - I just realized that the xor gibberish I wrote previously only works for integral data types

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to duplicate code that is already written, you'll need to use `strlen` to get the length of the strings:

```
unsigned int s1len = strlen(string1);
unsigned int s2len = strlen(string2);
if (s1len != s2len)
    return false;
```

If you cannot use the standard library functions (silly requirement):

```
unsigned int s1len = 0;
for (char* s = string1; *s != '\0'; s++, s1len++);
```

Will do the same thing (you have to do it for both strings).

After that, the swap is simple:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s1len; ++i)
{
    std::swap(string1[i], string2[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s1len; ++i)
{
    // these 3 lines are identical to what is done in std::swap
    char t = string1[i];
    string1[i] = string2[i];
    string2[i] = t;
}
```

You can also (defeating the purpose of the assignment, no doubt), simply change the pointer values:

```
bool swap_strings(char*& string1, char*& string2)
{
    char* t = string1;
    string1 = string2; // string1 will now point to string2
    string2 = t; // string2 will now point to what use to be string1
    return true;
}
```

I say it defeats the purpose of the assignment as you are not doing any copying, and the length requirement is irrelevant when you do it this way.  It also will not work (e.g. will not compile) when you are passing in arrays (e.g. if you declared your inputs as `char a[] = "abcd";` - which you have done in your `main`).

Comment: ok thanks a lot... but can I realise swapping also with pointer arithmetic? like assign the pointer to the other pointer or address...and like that swap it?

Comment: @user2774480:  You can pass in the pointers by reference and swap the pointer values.  I'll demonstrate in an update.

Comment: @ZacHowland Except they're not pointers on the caller side; they're arrays.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point.  Another reason why that method would defeat the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: @ZacHowland It doesn't just defeat the purpose; the call won't *compile* with the arrays as arguments. Pointers yes. Arrays no.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think arrays are implicit pointers that point to the first address of the array..

Comment: @ZacHowland, in your method with the swapping pointers,  char* t = string1;
    string1 = string2; // string1 will now point to string2
    string2 = t; // string2 will now point to what use to be string1
    return true;   I thought this also works, but somehow that doesnt work for me...

Comment: @user2774480 As WhozCraig pointed out, and I adjusted my answer to note, it will not compile when you are using arrays.  The point of your assignment is most likely to utilize the copy version, not the pointer version.

Comment: @user2774480 If you think arrays are implicit pointers, you're mistaken. They're not. A pointer is a variable that *holds* an address. An array doesn't "hold" an address; it ***is*** an address.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through the passed strings, and do a character-by-character swap.

e.g.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

bool swap_strings(char * const s1, char * const s2) {
    assert(s1 != nullptr);
    assert(s2 != nullptr);
    if (strlen(s1) != strlen(s2))
        return false;

    char * pch1 = s1;
    char * pch2 = s2;
    char temp;
    while (*pch1 != '\0') {
        temp = *pch1;
        *pch1 = *pch2;
        *pch2 = temp;

        ++pch1;
        ++pch2;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    char s1[] = "hallo1";
    char s2[] = "world2";

    if (swap_strings(s1, s2)) {
        cout << s1 << endl;
        cout << s2 << endl;
    }
}
```